# Booting Windows 7 Installer from USB Samsung Series 5

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, usb

I have a Samsung Series 5 laptop that came with Windows 8 Pre-Installed and a bunch of manufacturer stuff i didn't want.

I cleaned the DISK and installed ubuntu 14.04.

Now i was trying to install Windows 7, but i can't ever get it to boot from USB.

I tried the USB in a different computer and it boots right away.

I looked online for solutions and i find everywhere that i have to do:

- Disable Fast BIOS Mode
- Disable Secure Boot
- Set OS Mode Selection to : UEFI and CSM OS
- Set the USB as the top in the Boot Device Priority ( For some reason it never stays on top, but i have disabled all the other options without success)

The behavior that happens is:

If i don't touch anything, it goes directly to UBUNTU

If i press F10 to see boot options, i see my USB drive, but selecting it does nothing. If i press ESC, it goes to Ubuntu again.

I can boot from USB with an Ubuntu installer, but i can't seem to understand why Windows is not working.

Comment: What partition type are you using MBR or GPT. If you are using GPT that means the disk MUST be EFI bootable.  Likewise if your using MBR then UEFI should be disabled and only compatability mode used.

Comment: @Ramhound. I am not very familiar with that, but i am afraid of having messed up something with my partitions when i cleaned the disk when i installed ubuntu. My laptop has a 24Gb ssd like partition (MBR Only) and a 500Gb HDD (MBR Protective and GPT Present) (Found this out with gdisk in ubuntu). But i am almost sure that i tried all the possibilities between UEFI and CSM OS.

Comment: You can't have a disk that is both MBR and GPT they cannot co-exist.

Comment: As i said, i am not very familiar, but the info i get is that. Then it says: "Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.". But i already tried UEFI, CSM OS and both and no luck. :\. I'm really at a loss on this one.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to determine this.  Did you create MBR partitions or GPT partitions when installed Ubuntu?

Comment: I wasn't aware of those things when i created the partitions. I created an 3 partitions ext4, a swap and a boot(efi) partition to install ubuntu. I wasn't aware of those things when i installed it.

Comment: You just answered the question.  You have an EFI partition.  That means your using a GPT partitions.  This means any disk you boot to should contain EFI boot information in order to install an operating system and update the EFI partition so you can boot to it.